# Check for existence of an XML Schema Collection?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, exists, xml-schema-collection

writing scripts for Sql Server 2005. I am registering a schema with

```
CREATE XML SCHEMA COLLECTION [dbo].[MySchema] AS N'<xsd:schema ... >'
```

Now, as I make changes, I would like to drop it, say with a call to

```
DROP XML SCHEMA COLLECTION [dbo].[MySchema]
```

I run this stuff fairly frequently as I am developing, like

```
DROP ...
CREATE ...
```

but this presents problems on a first-run where the Schema does not exist. I would like to do something similar to

```
IF OBJECT_ID ('MySchema') IS NOT NULL
    DROP ...
CREATE ...
```

but `OBJECT_ID ('MySchema')` just returns `NULL`. Is there a proper way to test for existence of a registered Xml Schema Collection in Sql Server 2005?

muchos gracias mis amigos :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Check [sys.xml_schema_collections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190335.aspx):

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.xml_schema_collections WHERE name = 'MySchema')
```

Comment: To be 100% accurate you need to check also the schema_id, since XML schema collection objects are (database) schema contained and you may have multiple collections in different schemas (dbo.MySchema, foo.MySchema, bar.MySchema etc)